# Facing error regarding no API key found in the request & How to include properly

Tags: javascript, api, fetch-api, currency, rate

```
let myHeaders = new Headers();
 myHeaders.append("apikey", "QC9I9O0LPCFUfStGMD1h5CKcWN4Aehrk");

 let requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  redirect: 'follow',
  headers: myHeaders
 };

 const endpoint = "https://api.apilayer.com/currency_data/live";


async function fetchRates(base = "USD") {
    const res = await fetch(`${endpoint}?base=${base}`);
    const rates = await res.json();
    return rates;
  }

 async function convert(amount, from, to){
    // first check if we even have the rates to convert from that currency
    if (!ratesByBase[from]) {
        console.log(`Oh no! we don't have ${from} to convert it ${to}, so let 's go get it`);
        const rates = await fetchRates(from);
        console.log(rates);
        // store them for next time
        ratesByBase[from] = rates;
    }
 }
```

Upon running above code it's saying no API key found in the requestcan you tell me how to include it properly

Upon running the command in the console
convert(100, 'CAD', 'USD')
it's returing not fetching the rates instead showing error API key not found in the request even i have included as per guidance of documentation in the APIlayer dashbaord Please guide me what i'm messing it will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain to me how to use it I'm newer to javascript APIs

Comment: Try reading [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) - if that doesn't help, ask again

Comment: i tried reading but didn't helped please tell me with correct formate how to include it in the code properly I will be very grateful.